# A little issue I am facing in MVC2 with separating controllers and models in a different class libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, for-loop, project, controllers

If I am using a different class library project to hold my controllers then how will i create controllers. previously I use to right click on the controllers folder and then press add controller. Similarly, how will I create new strongly typed views?
When I select add view->strngly typed view then the list of data classes is empty.

Is there some configurations which I need to do ?

Comment: Alright now i have added the reference of Models project in my views project . and now i can create Strongly typed views. but this raises a small question.Do i really need to add the models reference in my View Project.Wont it violate the separation of concern which is the heart and soul of mvc?My view should not know anything about model right?Where should i keep my ViewModels?In same project or some other project? Thanks For ur support.

Comment: Personally I don't see the benefit in having your controllers in a different project, why can't they live in the web project?  They are purely a web concern.  The model on the other hand I always put in a seperate project.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i really need to add the models reference in my View Project.

Nope.

> Wont it violate the separation of concern which is the heart and 
>   soul of mvc?

Yup.

> My view should not know anything about model right?

Correct. Ideally your view should be aware of ViewModels but not the Model. I know it sounds like splitting hair but that's the way it is :)

Your Views should be aware of your ViewModels. Your Controllers should be aware of the Model and the ViewModels. Your Model should not be aware of any of them. Think of your Model as your "business logic" that is completely independent of your web app.

I have a blog post that explain this in more detail. Take a look at the "Model 2: MVC for the web" section.

http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/The-Model-View-Controller-is-dead-long-live-the-Model-View-Controller.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info... but my question remains the same....If i am using a different class library project to hold my controllers then how will i create controllers. previously i use to right click on the controllers folder and then press add controller?I wanna use t4 templates

Comment: I have no experience with T4 templates so I cannot comment on that. However as UpTheCreek commented on the original post I wonder why don't you leave the controllers on the web project.

Answer (score 0):

Now you right click on the controllers folder and press Add Class button and write a class deriving from [Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.aspx). As far as Views are concerned unless you implement a custom view engine they should reside in the web application.

Comment: But as i explained... i definately want to use t4 templates . because i am customizing them ... Now I can create a controller By keeping those folders i.e. Controller which were created by default but that wont be a good practice...I can simply create classes in controller library deriving from controller but i dont wanna do that...